# Forwarding headers requested with cURL

Tags: php, curl, header

I'm requesting a page with cURL and have the following options set:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
CURLOPT_NOBODY => 1,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
```

The request is returning two sets of headers because of a `Location:` header, like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 03 Mar 2013 13:13:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5
X-Debug-Useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Location: http://whateverdomain.com/file.zip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html

HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Date: Sun, 03 Mar 2013 13:08:45 GMT
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/octet-string
Content-Length: 309593
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"
Last-Modified: Sat, 07 Jul 2012 01:29:22 GMT
```

I would like to get all the headers of the last request (the `200 Ok` one) and "forward" those headers to the user.

I could explode the headers by `"\n"` and then send each one using `header()`, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: You just answered your own question. That is probably the best method indeed.

Comment: Alright. I was hoping there was a PHP function to send a collection of headers all at once rather than one at a time, but I suppose I can just make a function to loop through them all.